# Смена select в зависимости от значения

Tags: jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть выбор **пола** и ниже выбор **семейного положения**. Во втором пункты выборы должны меняться в зависимости от пола человека.

```
            <div class="form-group label-floating is-select mt-3 mb-1">
                <label class="control-label">Семейное положение</label>
                <select>
                    <option value="0">Не выбрано</option>

                    <option value="1" data-gender="man">Не женат</option>
                    <option value="2" data-gender="woman">Не замужем</option>

                    <option value="3">Встречаюсь</option>

                    <option value="4" data-gender="man">Помолвлен</option>
                    <option value="5" data-gender="woman">Помолвлена</option>

                    <option value="6" data-gender="man">Женат</option>
                    <option value="7" data-gender="woman">Замужем</option>

                    <option value="8">В гражданском браке</option>

                    <option value="9" data-gender="man">Влюблён</option>
                    <option value="10" data-gender="woman">Влюблена</option>

                    <option value="11">Всё сложно</option>
                    <option value="12">В активном поиске</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Здесь мы видим, что есть пункты **без data-gender - это общие (они не меняются)** и есть с **data-gender** со значением **man - мужские** и **woman - женские**

Это функция смены пола:

```
$(document).on("click", '.c-accent.account-gender', function() {
  var gender = $('.c-accent.account-gender').attr('data-gender');

  if (gender == 'man') {
      $(this).attr('data-gender','woman');
      $(this).html('Женский');
  } else {
      $(this).attr('data-gender','man');
      $(this).html('Мужской');
  }

});
```

и сама кнопка: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="c-accent account-gender" data-gender="man">Мужской</a>`

**Вопрос:** Как в select скрыть все элементы с `data-gender="woman"`, т.к стоит мужской, а при смене пола сделать наоборот скрыть все с `data-gender="man"`?

Comment: "функция смены пола" - смешно звучит. Лучше - "функция выбора пола".

Comment: (◕‿◕) ну да. Спасибо, за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", '.c-accent.account-gender', function() {
  var gender = $(this).data('gender');

  $("#status option").show();
  $("#status option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('gender') && $(this).data('gender') != gender;
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Gender
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="c-accent account-gender" data-gender="man" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="c-accent account-gender" data-gender="woman" />Female
<div class="form-group label-floating is-select mt-3 mb-1">
  <label class="control-label">Семейное положение</label>
  <select id="status">
    <option value="0">Не выбрано</option>

    <option value="1" data-gender="man">Не женат</option>
    <option value="2" data-gender="woman">Не замужем</option>

    <option value="3">Встречаюсь</option>

    <option value="4" data-gender="man">Помолвлен</option>
    <option value="5" data-gender="woman">Помолвлена</option>

    <option value="6" data-gender="man">Женат</option>
    <option value="7" data-gender="woman">Замужем</option>

    <option value="8">В гражданском браке</option>

    <option value="9" data-gender="man">Влюблён</option>
    <option value="10" data-gender="woman">Влюблена</option>

    <option value="11">Всё сложно</option>
    <option value="12">В активном поиске</option>
  </select>
</div>
```